# Data is not displaying in HTML Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have extracted data from JSON and trying to display it in HTML.But it is not displaying.I don't know what is causing the error.Please help me. see my code below

HTML CODE :

```
<body>
    <section class="card">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Movies Name</th>
                    <th>Release Year</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
    <script type=text/javascript src="Script.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getMovies(cb){
const httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', "http://localhost:3000/movies");
httpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
 if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
   cb(null,JSON.parse(httpRequest.response));
  }
};

httpRequest.send();
}

getMovies(function(err,movies) {
let td='',tr='';
let tbody=document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
tbody.innerHTML='';
let movie=movies[0];
let row=`
<th>${movie.name}</th>
<td>${movie.year}</td>
`;
let tr=document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML=row;

});
```

[image: This is the output i am getting]

Comment: Try adding some `console.log` and/or use the browser web console, debugger ...

Comment: please add the html file and the http request  result scheme

Comment: Uhm you did not append your `tr` anywhere in `document`

Comment: You  need to put your json data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably actually updating the DOM would be helpful

After `let tr=document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML=row;`

Call `tbody.appendChild(tr)`

If nothing changes try adding `console.log(httpRequest.response)` see if the data is actually coming

Comment: When i try this tbody.appendChild(tr). I am getting Object doesn't support property or method 'appendchild'. I am currently using IE 11

Comment: In that case you'll need to `tbody.innerHTML += tr.outerHTML;`